# How and where does a pom.xml will be configured to be invoked by a web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ide, pom.xml

I have been working on maven for some time but never had this question before, Many times I created my maven project using a IDE wizard which helps me to create a maven project which has pom.xml pre-configured or the other way is to convert a general java project into maven project which generates a pom.xml. I have a question what exactly happens in the background when we convert this java project into a maven project. What will be configured and how does the java project detects it has a pom.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `.project` file in the root of the Eclipse project, m2eclipse will add the `org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature` to it. This tells Eclipse that the m2e plugin will handle various stages of the project lifecycle, and m2e has a hybrid partially-internal and partially-external engine that applies the instructions in the `pom.xml` to the project. (For example, it finds the classpath placeholders that are marked as `maven.pomderived` and replaces them with the appropriate Maven dependencies.)